# How can I fill a map without returning Observable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

```
Completable addPlayersToPlayersMap(PlayerDao dao, Observable<Game> gamesORx)
    {
        return gamesORx
                .map(game -> game.id)
                .distinct()
                .flatMapCompletable(gameId ->
                                dao.players().loadPlayers(gameId)
                                   .flatMapCompletable(player -> {
                                       playersMap.put(playerId, player);
                                       return Completable.complete();
                                   })
                );
    }
```

I'd like to change flatMapCompletable -> flatMap && remove Completable.complete(), cause .put() is a sync operation, but in main() function I use Completable.mergeArray({addPlayersToMap, etc...}).

How do I fix this?

Comment: I should have used .doOnNext and then .ignoreElements to convert Observable -> Completable

Comment: You could convert the result to `Observable<Boolean>` or something; the `Completable` won't emit a value but will complete.